# Using imfilter_mex directly avoiding imfilter

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Recently I've started using imfilter function to make a convolution of an image with some kernel. I have to run this function several thousands of times. Therefore I decided to time calls that are made by this function.

It's turned out that really a lot of time is spent on argument checking, checking some toolbox preferences(functions like useIPPL(a,outSize,h,nonzero_h)) and other different preparations. Eventually everything comes to imfilter_mex calls.

Now the questions is: is I know my filters are not separable, I know that I will give correct parameters as inputs, how do I use properly this mex interface provided by Mathworks?

Initially, this mex located in private folder of image processing toolbox. Since it cannot be found be default, I've tried to moved in project's directory.

Since that time calls are randomly crashing with not obvious logic. Does anyone have any experience of using this mex directly?

Thank you

small update: crashes have Access Violation type, I have to kill matlab after each crash

Comment: Maybe there is a reason for all that argument checking...

Comment: @Dima I would say that if the problem is connected somehow to wrong arguments, I would get consistent picture of crashes, but not a random one. Of course, in case of using equal data from experiment to experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using internal functions directly is dangerous. So is moving internal mex files around. You do not know what safeguards you are bypassing, and what dependencies you may be breaking.

In this particular case, I would guess that your crash is caused by passing the wrong data type to the mex function. This is exactly the type of thing that all that parameter validation protects you from.

If you need to convolve many images with the same kernel, then you can pass the whole stack of images into `imfilter`. This will probably give you the speed up you want, without having to reverse-engineer MATLAB. By the way, keep in mind that by default `imfilter` performs correlation rather than convolution.

**Edit:** speaking of datatypes: if you can use `uint8` for your image and your kernel, that should speed things up.